# How to add Hg clone options to Mercurial Jenkins plug-in

Tags: mercurial, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

We are migrating from CCNet to Jenkins and have started to use Mercurial. The repo is on a seperate server than Jenkins so it needs to clone over the network. In my tests `hg clone` using the  `--uncompressed` option is much faster for pulling over the network (as discussed in the [documentation](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#clone)), so I want to tell the [Mercurial Jenkins plug-in](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Mercurial+Plugin) to add it. I see that Jenkins is running this command to update the local repo:

`C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\hg.exe" --debug clone --rev default --noupdate http://remoteserver/project D:\local_repo\project`

I want it to run this command:

`C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\hg.exe" --debug --uncompressed clone --rev default --noupdate http://remoteserver/project D:\local_repo\project`

I suspect I might have to modify the jenkin's XML project directly because I didn't see a place to do it in the Jenkin's GUI, but I can't find any documentation for this.

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't be needed: Jenkins will clone your remote repository only once, and then do (small) updates.

Jenkins has an internal cache with clones of remote repositories, and all jobs linked to the same remote repository will in fact be updated using this cache.

Comment: We have the same need - mercurial under Windows platform cannot clone a large repo without the `--uncompressed` flag due to win related issues (it does alright on the Linux and Mac OSX platforms).